# Open a webpage when closing a browser

Tags: firefox, browser

My company has started using an online attendance system. We are supposed to sign-in manually when we come in the office AND signout while leaving. I have set it as my homepage so that I don't forget about signing in. But signing out is still a problem.

Can I configure my browser (Firefox 42.0 on Mac) to open a specific URL while closing the browser so that I don't forget to sign out? Leaving the page open in a tab is not working for me because sometimes I close all the tabs without looking at them.

Comment: You may be better to restart PC each day at a given time so if you forget, it's done. Not sure if IT will be happy with this but... that's your decision :@)

Comment: You could ask the developers to include a pop up on page exit. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1704533/intercept-page-exit-event